# wxPython: show number repeatedly

Tags: python, wxpython, wxtextctrl

I'm a very beginner of Python Programming, and now I'm wondering why my widgets cannot show number repeatedly.
That is, I'd like to let the text show numbers from 1 to 9, but in the while loop, it only shows 9....
Any suggestions?

Here is my code(Python version: 2.6):

```
#!/user/bin/python


import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,
                      'Show Number',
                      size = (200,150),
                      style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER 
| wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |  wx.CLOSE_BOX)
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    widgetPanel=wx.Panel(self, -1)
    widgetPanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')

    # Buttons for play the simulation
    playButton = wx.Button(widgetPanel, -1, "Play", pos=(10,10), size=(30,30))

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.play, playButton)
    playButton.SetDefault()

    # Time
    self.timeText = wx.TextCtrl(widgetPanel, -1, "", pos=(10, 50), 
                            size =(100,30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
    self.timeText.SetBackgroundColour('white')
    self.timeText.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

def play(self, event):
    #self.timeText.SetValue("19:32")
    self.show_num()

def show_num(self):
    x = 0
    while(x < 10):
        self.timeText.SetValue(str(x))
        x += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answer said, you need to give time to your app to update.
I have made a few additions to your code to make it work:

```
import wx
import time
import thread

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id,
                          'Show Number',
                          size = (200,150),
                          style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.RESIZE_BORDER 
    | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION |  wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        widgetPanel=wx.Panel(self, -1)
        widgetPanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        # Buttons for play the simulation
        playButton = wx.Button(widgetPanel, -1, "Play", pos=(10,10), size=(30,30))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.play, playButton)
        playButton.SetDefault()

        # Time
        self.timeText = wx.TextCtrl(widgetPanel, -1, "", pos=(10, 50), 
                                size =(100,30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
        self.timeText.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.timeText.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

    def play(self, event):
        #self.timeText.SetValue("19:32")
        #self.show_num()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.show_num,())

    def show_num(self):
        x = 0
        while(x < 10):
            self.timeText.SetValue(str(x))
            time.sleep(1)
            x += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Notice that `time.sleep(1)` pauses the while loop for 1 second so that the display can be updated. You can reduce or increase the pause time as you desire.

Comment: Brilliant! After @Joran Beasley 's answer, I tried the timer and it worked! And now your code seems even better than mine! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

you need to give your app the chance to update .... the easiest and most correct way of doing this is to use timers instead of a loop  ... I have included a minimal example

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = wx.Frame(None,-1,"Counter")
btn = wx.Button(f,-1,"Click Me!")
timer = wx.Timer() # this will update the count

def onUpdateButton(evt):
    next_int = int(btn.GetLabel())+1
    btn.SetLabel(str(next_int))
    if next_int > 10:
        timer.Stop()
        btn.Enable(True)


def onButtonClick(event):
    btn.SetLabel("0")
    btn.Enable(False)
    timer.Start(1000) # 1 second updates

timer.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,onUpdateButton)    
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,onButtonClick)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

it is probably obvious to most users, however may be worth mentioning that instead of keeping a variable with the current count i am just using the label string

Answer (score 0):

I experienced an update issue with:

```
self.timeText.SetValue(str(x))
time.sleep(1)
x += 1
```

I added a wx.YieldIfNeeded() before the sleep:

```
self.timeText.SetValue(str(x))
wx.YieldIfNeeded()
wx.sleep(1)
x += 1
```

This makes sure the GUI is updated and other events are handled.
I also would use the wx.Sleep(). This prevents using an other library...